# how to open new activity when you click an item in spinner and pass data, and is it possible we cant open new activity through spinner?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
public class BekaaActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
Spinner bekaa=null;
Intent intent;
String[] info;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bekaaarea);
    bekaa=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    bekaa.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterViewparent){}

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent,View view,int pos,long id){




    if(((TextView)view).getText().equals("Sohmor")){

         String[] info = {"Adel","70858243","8-10-12","70$","sohmor"};





                Intent i = new Intent("net.learn2develop.AutocarActivity");
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putStringArray("strings",info);

                i.putExtras(extras);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);



    }



//tv1.setText(((TextView)view).getText());

}
```

Whenever i click Sohmor item, the application crashes, i don't know why . i followed the error and i find it when i want to start new Activity
here's the log 
04-05 22:55:02.157: D/dalvikvm(12477): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 27% free 2752K/3728K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
04-05 22:55:02.157: I/dalvikvm-heap(12477): Grow heap (frag case) to 2.999MB for 294384-byte allocation
04-05 22:55:02.187: D/dalvikvm(12477): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 25% free 3039K/4016K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
04-05 22:55:02.477: I/PGA(12477): Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 12477, tid = 12477
04-05 22:55:02.487: I/PGA(12477): New SOCKET connection: com.example.liutransportations (pid 12477, tid 12477)
04-05 22:55:11.077: W/InputEventReceiver(12477): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
04-05 
22:55:11.227: W/Instrumentation(12477): Unresolved intent: cmp: null
04-05 22:55:11.227: W/Instrumentation(12477): Unresolved intent: data: 
04-05 
22:55:11.227: D/AndroidRuntime(12477): Shutting down VM
04-05 
22:55:11.227: W/dalvikvm(12477): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d28b20)
04-05 22:55:11.227: I/Process(12477): Sending signal. PID: 12477 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
Intent i = new Intent("net.learn2develop.AutocarActivity");
```

if you have an activity with name "AutocarActivity" and you want to open it try this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AutocarActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putStringArray("strings",info);

                i.putExtras(extras);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

**Not: You must to declare the activity in your manifest file**
So you must to replace

```
Intent i = new Intent("net.learn2develop.AutocarActivity");
```

With :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AutocarActivity.class);
```

For more info about intents [Intent class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)